# Install php-devel

Tags: php, centos

I would like to install php-devel on my server(CentOS 6.5).

```
yum install php-devel
```

However, I encountered the following error.

```
Error: php54-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
Error: php54 conflicts with php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
Error: php54-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: This should probably be migrated over to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have to chose between packages 5.4 and 5.3

i'll suggests to do :

```
yum remove php.*

sudo yum install php53-common php5-devel php5-cli
```